# How to remove a specific data from the beginning of the json/avro schema file and the last bracket from the end of the file?

Tags: json, shell, unix, sed, apache-nifi

I am extracting the schema of a table from an oracle DB using Apache Nifi which I need to use to create a table in BigQuery. The extract SQL processor in NiFi is giving me a schema file which I am saving in my home directory. Now to use this schema file in BigQuery, I need to remove a certain part of the schema file from the beginning and end. How do I do this in unix using sed/awk?

Here is the content of the output file:

```
Obj^A^D^Vavro.schema<88>^L{"type":"record","name":"NiFi_ExecuteSQL_Record","namespace":"any.data","fields":[{"name":"FEED_SEQUENCE","type":["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":38,"scale":0}]},{"name":"FEED_UNIQUE_NAME","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"COUNTRY_CODE","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"EXTRACTION_TYPE","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"PROJECT_SEQUENCE","type":["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":38,"scale":0}]},{"name":"CREATED_BY","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"CREATED_DATE","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]},{"name":"UPDATED_BY","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"UPDATED_DATE","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]},{"name":"FEED_DESC","type":["null","string"]}]}^Tavro.codec^Hnull^@àÂ<87>)[ù<8b><97><90>"õ^S<98>[<98>±
```

I want to remove the Initial part `Obj^A^D^Vavro.schema<88>^L{"type":"record","name":"NiFi_ExecuteSQL_Record","namespace":"any.data","fields":`
and the ending part `}^Tavro.codec^Hnull^@àÂ<87>)[ù<8b><97><90>"õ^S<98>[<98>±` from the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that You want to remove everything outside first [ and last ]:

```
sed 's/^[^[]*//;s/[^]]*$//'
```

Test:

```
$ cat out.file
Obj^A^D^Vavro.schema<88>^L{"type":"record","name":"NiFi_ExecuteSQL_Record","namespace":"any.data","fields":[{"name":"FEED_SEQUENCE","type":["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":38,"scale":0}]},{"name":"FEED_UNIQUE_NAME","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"COUNTRY_CODE","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"EXTRACTION_TYPE","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"PROJECT_SEQUENCE","type":["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":38,"scale":0}]},{"name":"CREATED_BY","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"CREATED_DATE","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]},{"name":"UPDATED_BY","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"UPDATED_DATE","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]},{"name":"FEED_DESC","type":["null","string"]}]}^Tavro.codec^Hnull^@àÂ<87>)[ù<8b><97><90>"õ^S<98>[<98>±
$ sed 's/^[^[]*//;s/[^]]*$//' out.file
[{"name":"FEED_SEQUENCE","type":["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":38,"scale":0}]},{"name":"FEED_UNIQUE_NAME","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"COUNTRY_CODE","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"EXTRACTION_TYPE","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"PROJECT_SEQUENCE","type":["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":38,"scale":0}]},{"name":"CREATED_BY","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"CREATED_DATE","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]},{"name":"UPDATED_BY","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"UPDATED_DATE","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]},{"name":"FEED_DESC","type":["null","string"]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ExtractAvroMetadata`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-avro-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.avro.ExtractAvroMetadata/) processor to extract only the **`avro.schema`** from the `avro flowfile`.

- In the processor for `Metadata Keys` property specify value as **`avro.schema`**, then processor extracts avro metadata and keep as flowfile attribute.
- Use the attribute value`(${avro.schema}` in **`ReplaceText`** processor to overwrite the content of flowfile and create the table.

Answer (score 0):

the data in 'd' file, by gnu sed,

```
sed -E 's/^[^\[]+(\[\{.+\})[^\}]+/\1/' d
```

consider use regex in Perl if you'd work on Json string manipulation